# Drupal ajax page loading instead of re-freshing

Tags: jquery, ajax, drupal, dynamic, pageload

I am attempting something different with a new site. I am using AJAX to dynamically load the entire page content instead of allowing the HTML to refresh as normal.

If you visit http://test2omniforce.co.uk/node/2 and click on the links on the left, you will see it works fine for text content.

However, the problem now is the carousel images above. Each page has it's own image(s). How might I dynamically load complex image structures such as that carousel?

PS: You can inspect the XML data returned using some kind of Firebug tool.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Drupal 6 you can take a look at the [ajaxIt](http://drupal.org/project/ajaxit) module. It lets you define the DIVs whose content you want to load dynamically when a link is clicked, so you should be able to refresh both the carousel and the text area at the same time. I've used the module for loading the main content areas of a site dynamically, and it has worked quite nicely.